# Any decent IMAP documentation or tutorial or examples?

Tags: gmail, imap

Is there a good tutorial on how to navigate around IMAP? For example how do you get 20 most recent messages from gmail inbox?

I'm trying to use sort, but GMail Server does not seem to support this command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing beats reading the RFC ([RFC3501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501)). It might sound monumental, but IMAP is indeed a complex protocol, and the RFC explains all the rules. From there, just get hands-on experience by typing raw commands. You can use telnet to mess around on a non-SSL system. For Gmail you'll need something like my [IMAPTalk](http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/projects/imaptalk/) client.

You can get the 20 most recent messages by first finding out the highest message sequence number in the folder, like so:

```
FETCH * (UID)
```

This will give you the UID in brackets, but the response will include the sequence number at the beginning.

Then, just deduct 20 from that value. For instance, if the highest sequence number is 88, then just do

```
FETCH 68:* (BODY[])
```

That will retrieve the messages.

Comment: When you first SELECT a folder, you will get an EXISTS response, which will tell you the highest sequence number in the mailbox.

Comment: Yes actually, that's even easier. +1 for that.